# updating state in reducer not updating component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was trying to update my state from an api, using [this approach](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-an-item-in-an-array). So I created the following code in my reducer:

```
export default function(state = null, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ROUTING_BOOKS:
            return action.payload.data;
        case UPDATE_BOOK:
            let newVals = state.map((item)=>{
                if(item.MatItemKey === action.meta.book.MatItemKey){
                    return update(item, {$merge: action.payload.data})

                }else{
                    return item
                }
            });
            console.log(newVals);
            return newVals
    }
    return state
}
```

newVals returns back the values I want in my state. However, the component that is using this reducer using connect:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        routing: state.activeRouting,
        routingBooks: state.routingBooks
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RoutingTable);
```

ROUTING_BOOKS updates the component, but my calls to UPDATE_BOOK appear to update the reducer, but not the RoutingTable component.

EDIT: Sample data from UPDATE_BOOK

> [{"RoutingStepKey":4752755,"MaterReqPer":1,"MatItemKey":216158,"MatReqPc":1,"StepID":"000010","OperationType":"M","OperationDesc1":"Default Material Step","LongDesc":"Who Am I?"},{"RoutingStepKey":4752756,"MaterReqPer":1,"MatItemKey":216056,"MatReqPc":1,"StepID":"000020","OperationType":"M","OperationDesc1":"Default Material Step","LongDesc":"Mammals Love Their Babies"},{"RoutingStepKey":4752758,"MaterReqPer":1,"MatItemKey":218213,"MatReqPc":1,"StepID":"000030","OperationType":"M","OperationDesc1":"Default Material Step","LongDesc":"My Forest"}]

Sample data from Update_Book:

> [{"RoutingStepKey":4752755,"MaterReqPer":1,"MatItemKey":216158,"MatReqPc":1,"StepID":"000010","OperationType":"M","OperationDesc1":"Default Material Step","LongDesc":"Who Am I?"...more data added},{"RoutingStepKey":4752756,"MaterReqPer":1,"MatItemKey":216056,"MatReqPc":1,"StepID":"000020","OperationType":"M","OperationDesc1":"Default Material Step","LongDesc":"Mammals Love Their Babies"...more data added},{"RoutingStepKey":4752758,"MaterReqPer":1,"MatItemKey":218213,"MatReqPc":1,"StepID":"000030","OperationType":"M","OperationDesc1":"Default Material Step","LongDesc":"My Forest"...more data added}]

Combine Reducers:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import books from './books';
import routings from './routings';
import activeBook from './activeBook';
import activeRouting from './activeRouting';
import options from './options';
import login from './login';
import uiState from './uiState';
import routingBooks from './routingBooks';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    books,
    routingBooks,
    activeBook,
    activeRouting,
    options,
    routings,
    login,
    uiState
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Could you show what `newVals` contains? And what `action.payload.data` contains in your other reducer?

Comment: seems like state is not being updated, if you log componentWillUpdate and manually compare props, do you see a difference, that will give you a clue. Seems like you are returning a new state so it should work, which leads me to believe something wrong with your `combineReducers`

Comment: Could you show us your `reducers.js` (or wherever you have your `combineReducers`)?

Comment: One more question, I answered this thinking my data showed up, but now it is not again. Weird, is it bad form to have a connected component call to another connected component? I have that setup right now and my child never gets the connected info.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you can map null values.  I would change your reducer parameters from `export default function(state = null, action){` to `export default function(state = [], action){`

Comment: Weird @MEnf I got my connection to work. But it is still sporatic. When I put in your state = [] it went back to not working. I would agree with you though, I would think having a default array for state would help it, not hinder it.

Answer (score 2):

Posting in the answer section because the comment section isn't a good place to display code examples.

Maybe try something along these lines?  I'm unfamiliar with the immutable.js library, but I'm assuming you're attempting to merge an object in an array with an updated object when a book's key matches a key that exists in the reducer.

I also think your default condition lived outside of the switch statement which could be causing you problems.

```
export default function(state = [], action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ROUTING_BOOKS: {
            return action.payload.data;
        }
        case UPDATE_BOOK: {
            const newVals = state.map(item => {
                if(item.MatItemKey === action.meta.book.MatItemKey){
                    return { ...item, ...action.payload.data }
                }
                return item
            });
            return newVals
        }
        default:{
            return state
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, if your reducer is successfully updating data but your component is not then that usually means your reducer is not a pure function.  Make sure you are not mutating data inside your reducer at all.

Comment: In my case I am able to change state using Object.assign() , but its not reflecting/rerendering my connected component. after I added two things 1.withRouter 2.combineReducers

Comment: It sounds like your state is mutating somewhere down the line, but I can't really tell without looking at the code.  Object.assign returns a new object, so the problem probably isn't stemming form there.

Answer (score 1):

Use object assign or some other way to create immutable object.(like immutable.js)

Assuming your initial state is defined as:

```
state={ vals: '' }

return Object.assign({}, state, {
    vals: newVals
  })
```

Or you can use immutable.js for example

```
return Immutable.fromJS({
    vals: newVals
  });
```

Comment: I really don't want to use immutable.js if I don't have it. It changes the way I am making calls in my project and I would rather do it with just js and redux. Further I am already using immutability-helper as the tutorial I referenced suggests.

Comment: You dont have to use immutable.js, you can use Object.assign, which is a part of ES6 standard